# Dart extension function visible only if is in the same file where it is called

Tags: flutter, dart, extension-methods

Let's say I create two files. In first I create an extension function and call it from class in another file.

File **date_extensions.dart**:

```dart
import 'package:date_format/date_format.dart';

extension on DateTime {
  String getSQLFriendly() => formatDate(this, ["yyyy", "-", "MM", "-", "dd", " ", "HH", ":", "mm", ":", "ss"]);
}
```

and file **some_date_class.dart**:

```dart
import 'date_extensions.dart';

class SomeClassWithDate{

  DateTime dateTime;

  SomeClassWithDate(this.dateTime);

  toString() => dateTime.getSQLFriendly();

}
```

Now, I get an error:

```
lib/test/some_date_class.dart:9:26: Error: The method 'getSQLFriendly' isn't defined for the class 'DateTime'.
 - 'DateTime' is from 'dart:core'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'getSQLFriendly'.
  toString() => dateTime.getSQLFriendly();
```

Now, when I put extension function in the same file where I call it, everything works fine.

Is this a bug, a feature or am I doing something wrong? I would like that the latter is the answer. :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Anonymous Dart extensions (those without a name) will be only visible to the file where they are in.

If you want to use it on other files, give it a name.

```
import 'package:date_format/date_format.dart';

extension MyExtension on DateTime {}
```

This probably should be added to [Dart extensions documentation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/extension-methods).

Comment: Yeah, I guess that should be added. :D

Comment: It is mentioned on that page ("To create a local extension that’s visible only in the library where it’s declared, either omit the extension name or give it a name that starts with an underscore (_)."), but I do think it's a little hard to find if you're not looking for it.